# Add distance onto coordinate

Tags: math

I have a unit vector, a distance and a coordinate and I would like to calculate the new coordinate given by adding the distance onto the coordinate in the given direction. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode, assuming you're using Cartesian coordinates.

```
new_coord.x = distance * unit.x + coord.x
new_coord.y = distance * unit.y + coord.y
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the vector by the distance then add the resulting vector to the point.

Answer (score 1):

If with a unit vector, you mean a vector with distance 1. You can find the coordinate bij multiplying all coordinates with the distance.

```
V = V unit * distance


V unit = (1/2 sqrt(3), 1/2)
distance = 6

==>

V = (3 sqrt(3), 3)
```